# Django average grouped by foreign key

Tags: python-3.x, django

I have this model

```py
class Makes(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(...)
    instrument = models.ForeignKey(
        to='users.Instrument',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    begin_date = models.DateField(
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
    end_date = models.DateField(
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
```

And I want to get the average, for each instrument, of the timedelta between `begin_date` and `end_date`

I tried this:

```py
from django.db.models import Avg, F, ExpressionWrapper, fields
duration = ExpressionWrapper(F('end_date') - F('begin_date'), output_field=fields.DurationField())

instrument_data = (
    Makes.objects
    .exclude(begin_date__isnull=True)
    .exclude(end_date__isnull=True)
    .annotate(duration=duration)
    .aggregate(average=Avg(duration))
    # I can't even figure out how to also get the instrument name here
)
```

But that got me the average of all the durations, and not the average duration per instrument.

I also tried this:

```py
instrument_data = (
    Makes.objects
    .exclude(begin_date__isnull=True
    .exclude(end_date__isnull=True)
    .annotate(duration=Avg(duration))
    .values('instrument__instrument_name', 'duration')
)
```

But that got me the "Average" of each individual Makes instance

so in conclusion, how do I get a result that looks a bit like this

```
<QuerySet[
  {
    'instrument__instrument_name': 'alt-viool',
    'duration': datetime.timedelta(days=142)
  },
  {
    'instrument__instrument_name': 'contrabas',
    'duration': datetime.timedelta(days=62)
  },
  {
    'instrument__instrument_name': 'viool',
    'duration': datetime.timedelta(days=49)
  }
]>
```

Comment: Hint: Querying from `Instrument` is easier in this case.

Comment: How so? Makes contains all the information I want..

Comment: instrument_data = (
    Makes.objects
    .exclude(begin_date__isnull=True
    .exclude(end_date__isnull=True)
    .annotate(duration=Avg(duration))
    .values('instrument__instrument_name', 'duration').distinct('instrument__instrument_name')
). if you have postgresql it should work

Comment: Thank you, though unfortunately I am using MySQL. If you can post this as an answer I can accept it